# how to read unsupported format xls in pyexcel or pandas

Tags: python, xlsx

## I used pyexcel and pandas to read my xls but faild

```
import pyexcel as pe
def convert_xls_to_xlsx(input_path, output_path):
    # Read the XLS file using pyexcel_xls
    data = pe.read(file_name = input_path)
    print("read ok")

xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xff\xfe\x8f^\xf7S\t\x00'
```

## I hope someone tell me which python package can be used to solve this question? except pandas,openpyxl which i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your file may be corrupted. Try to open it with any program that supports `.xls` files like LibreOffice or Excel, resave it, and try again.

Note that pandas will automatically use `xlrd` because it is the only engine that supports `.xls` files.

If the saving trick doesn't work I suggest you import `xlrd` directly and try to use it.

You can find more here: https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: now i solve this question by adding encoding parameter:df = pd.read_csv(input_path, encoding='utf-16le', sep='\t')